# Django Heroku - ImportError after uploading

Tags: python, django, heroku

I successfully  uploaded my Django app to Heroku, but when I open my app, I got `ImportError` which says:
`Your WhiteNoise configuration is incompatible with WhiteNoise v4.0
This can be fixed by following the upgrade instructions at:
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/changelog.html#v4-0`

And later:
`Error during template rendering. In template /app/templates/base.html`

In base.html file I have:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
...
```

And error points at line with css/home.css

In my **settings.py** I have:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
django_heroku.settings(locals())
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

During uploading to Heroku I set config to: `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MY_PROJECT.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Does anybody know why I have this error after uploading and open app?

**EDIT:**

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
```

I set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0 and still I get the same error. Im trying to deploy this app: [my github app](https://github.com/f4lco0n/git-efforts)

Comment: Did you enable whitenoise through the middleware setting? Or wsgi.py?

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes, I added 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE list in settings.py

Comment: Please check you removed it from wsgi.py

Comment: Why did you disable collectstatic and don’t have a STATIC_ROOT setting?

Comment: You need to run collectstatic to be able to use the compressed manifest file storage.

Comment: @dirkgroten I added edit with wsgi.py

Comment: @dirkgroten I have static_url and staticfiles_dirs. Should I rename it?

Comment: No you still need those. STATIC_ROOT is to define where collectstatic should save the files.

Comment: Look at [my blog post](https://www.dedi.co/blog/entries/2018/12/17/deploying-static-files-aws-django-part-1) its not exactly your situation but it should help you understand what the various settings mean.

Comment: Set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static'))`

Comment: @dirkgroten I added edit

Answer (score 1):

Your `STATICFILES_STORAGE` setting is wrong it should be:

```py
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

i.e. you have `.django.` where you should have `.storage.`

Comment: Ok, it works to some extent. App is on: https://demo-git-efforts.herokuapp.com/. If you enter correct link to repo with at least 2 users and inspect network, you will see that bokeh library is not loaded.